# PFX / Software Certificate Not Functioning Correctly

Tags: powershell, certificate, pfx

I have a script that was built and tested by another state, with the intent of scanning a certain directory on every computer in our Domain, looking for .pfx files, and then copying them to a storage directory while logging the action, once a month.  From there, we can on the administrative side, inspect the certificate and see if we need to keep it or not.

So the script is supposed to do three basic things:

1. Find .pfx files in a directory.
2. Copy any file to a storage directory.
3. Log all of these actions in a monthly report.

What it's NOT doing, is Copying the File or Logging it.  I've looked through the script and then explored other contents on this website, and I can't seem to figure out WHAT I'm, or this script is doing wrong.  I need it to copy the file and write to a specified location like it did in the other state where it was ran.  The script is below, with certain sensitive information omitted.

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=CAC Not Required,OU=DESKTOPS,OU=WORKSTATIONS,OU=WIN10,OU=,OU=,DC=,DC=,DC=,DC="
$destination = "\\NGVT-SA7V-02\Software\10 - Patching Logs\Soft Cert Clean"

foreach ($computer in $computers){

    $client = $computer.name

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $client -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {

            $outputdir = "$destination\$client"
            $ext = "*.pfx"
            $filerepo = "$outputdir\Files"
            $files = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$client\c$\Users -Filter $ext -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                if (!$files){

                    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "There are no .pfx files on $client."
                }

                else {

                    if (Test-Path -Path $outputdir) {

                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "PFX files found on $client"
                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Gray "Output directory exists for $client"

                        $files | Select fullname, length | Out-File $outputdir\PFX_List.txt
                        $files | Copy-Item -Destination $filerepo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Files moved to share server for $client."

                    }

                    else {

                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "PFX files found on $client"

                        New-Item -ItemType Directory $outputdir -Force | Out-Null
                        New-Item -ItemType Directory $filerepo -Force | Out-Null

                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Output directory and File repo created for $client"

                        $files| Select fullname, length | Out-File $outputdir\PFX_List.txt
                        $files | Copy-Item -Destination $filerepo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Files moved to share server for $client."

                    }
                }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$client is not online."
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think you need to change `if (Test-Path -Path $outputdir)` into `if (Test-Path -Path $filerepo)`, because that is the destination for the copied files. Now, you are just testing for the parentfolder of this destination.

Comment: You can also shorten the code considerably by doing `if (!(Test-Path -Path $filerepo -PathType Container)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory $filerepo -Force | Out-Null }` and then do all the stuff you are duplicating in the `if...else` blocks.

Comment: Sweet.  I'm off work today, but on Monday I'll be back in and give this a shot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I clearly do not have your environment in which to test, the following code might work. I used @Theo's suggestion about directory creation. The `New-Item` cmdlet will create intermediate directories, so there is no need to call it twice.

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=CAC Not Required,OU=DESKTOPS,OU=WORKSTATIONS,OU=WIN10,OU=,OU=,DC=,DC=,DC=,DC="
$destination = "\\NGVT-SA7V-02\Software\10 - Patching Logs\Soft Cert Clean"
$ext = "*.pfx"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $client = $computer.name

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $client -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $outputdir = "$destination\$client"
        $filerepo = "$outputdir\Files"
        $files = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$client\c$\Users -Filter $ext -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        if (!$files) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "There are no .pfx files on $client."
        } else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "PFX files found on $client"

            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $filerepo)) {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory $filerepo -Force | Out-Null
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Output directory and File repo created for $client"
            }

            $files | Select fullname, length | Out-File $outputdir\PFX_List.txt
            $files | Copy-Item -Destination $filerepo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Files moved to share server for $client."
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$client is not online."
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a shot on Monday.  I've been killing myself over this because it worked in one place (another state's Domain) and not mine.